# Is it possible to insert Google Maps API into CSS style sheet

Tags: html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm  using the web hosting service agent ignition and I'm trying to insert the google maps API into one of my webpages. The setup is almost entirely menu driven but there is one section where I can place CSS and HTML code. I was wondering if it would be possible to put the google maps API code here and make it work this way? Can I put the Javascript within the HTML and run it as so?

Comment: The Google Maps Javascript API requires javascript, not just css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely not. If your CMS is allowing custom css that will likely be output within `<style>` tags and there's no way to tell the browser to ignore them and consider the code within as JavaScript which is what Google Maps requires.

Comment: I figured that I can run HTML code in this section as well. Do you know how I could insert the javascript into the HTML and run it this way?

Comment: Does your CMS allow javascript in the HTML code section?

Comment: Yeah javascript can run within the HTML

Comment: Think you just need to give it a shot then.